# libtool error with xcodebuild command

Tags: ios, xcode, static-libraries, cocoapods

I am getting following error when try to build xcode project using xcodebuild command.

I have written this script under build phase of project to build my library for different architecture.
I am following this [link](http://red-glasses.com/index.php/tutorials/xcode4-make-a-library-in-one-file-that-works-on-both-device-and-simulator/) to build universal library.

I have integrated one library using cocoapods.
[image]
My Static library is using that library.

Why? Any idea...

If I try to run the same command on terminal I am getting following error - 
`The following build commands failed:
    Libtool /Users/USERNAME/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData/MYPROJNAME-gfxfnyljssfzaphblnapnusfvpse/Build/Products/Debug-iphoneos/libMYPROJNAME.a normal armv7`